# Facebook Linter can't download image or it is too small

Tags: facebook, wordpress, share, facebook-social-plugins, jetpack

Hello i have a wordpress blog with open graph tags generated by jetpack. My problem is that some times facebook cant pull article image and facebook linter warns me about:

og:image could not be downloaded or is too small

Give this to facebook linter tool

http://www.radioevros.gr/2014/05/sobaro-troxaio-ston-notio-kombo-tou-soufliuo/

It will grab the image but the warning is still there , sometimes the image is not pulling.

Image hotlink protection is off and image is bigger than 200x200.

Thanks